# Generate Access token with oauth2 authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, graphql

From my microservice implemented in Spring boot if any request is render then it should pass through some authentication  mechanism. In my case , both authentication and authorization is done by 3rd party server and they have provided the require clientId and secureKey.
basically they have share the below details:
Request:

```
POST https://auth.abc.com/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: YourPartnerService/1.2.3

{
  "audience": "https://graphql.abc.com",
  "client_id": "CLIENT_ID_HERE",
  "client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

**Expected Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "access_token": "PARTNER_TOKEN_HERE",
  "expires_in": 86400,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

**Approach:**

1. Created a spring boot project
2. added require maven dependency for oAuth2,SpringSecurity
3. created a rest end point which will call that 3rd party authentication endpoint.

I am unable to generate the access token .
Please help me out to find the suitable approach to generate the access token and set it as a bearer token in cache.

Comment: If the authorization is done by 3rd party so for what purpose you've added the oAuth2 dependency.

Comment: You've mentioned that the token will be issued by 3rd party then clearly you just need to check with the request. If that's ok then the 3rd party service can only give you more details about what went wrong for token request.

Comment: So, only calling this 3rd party auth api will be sufficient.I have set all those request param in application.yml .

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Unauthorised 401 error code.

Comment: And I want to persist that token with all further request for that certain duration. I know that I need to set this token as bearer token . But I am confused how every subsequent request authorize the token.

Comment: please post the code that is making the request